# C# Multi level user login

Tags: c#, authentication

Hi i try to make multi level login, so i use this code, but it's doesn't work

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

the error was showed on `string s1 = dr[3].ToString();`

CODE:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Server=GATEWAY-PC\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=train_system;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM employer WHERE username='" + textBox1.Text + "'AND password='" + textBox2.Text + "'",conn);

    conn.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr ;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            
            
    int count = 0;
    while (dr.Read())
    {
       count += 1;
    }

    if (count == 1)
    {
       string s1 = dr[3].ToString();

       if ( s1 == "1")
       {
          MessageBox.Show("Login as Shedule");
       }
       else if (s1 == "2")
       {
          MessageBox.Show("Login as Operation");
       }
    }
    else if (count < 1)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("error");
    }
}
```

Comment: please show the schema of employer table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite it like this

```
if (dr.Read())
{
   string s1 = dr[3].ToString(); //this line tries to get 4th column. So, your query should return 4 columns.

   if ( s1 == "1")
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Login as Shedule");
   }
   else if (s1 == "2")
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Login as Operation");
   }
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("error");
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's Worked!! :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly saying that `dr[3]` doesn't exist!

Use debug tools to find out what is in `dr` at executing the line `string s1 = dr[3].ToString();`